# Accept: application/xml no longer working after Autofac implementation on RESTful WCF Services

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, autofac

I recently implemented Autofac as the IoC Container on our C#.Net solution that contains RESTful WCF services. This seemed to be working fairly well until some of our consumers noticed that they could no longer get responses in XML by setting the Accept header to application/xml. Now it will only return JSON regardless of the Accept header.

I think the problem stems from replacing `Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"` with `Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf"` in the Service.svc file which is required to implement Autofac.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Below is a simplified, but representative code sample.

Service.svc:

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
    Language="C#" 
    Service="MySolution.MyService, MySolution.MyService" 
    CodeBehind="WcfServiceImplementations/Service.cs"
    Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf"
%>
```

IMyService.cs:

```
...
[ServiceContract(Name = "MyService", Namespace = "WebServices")]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Object))]
public interface IMyService
{
    /// Comments
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Method/{Id}",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Object MyMethod(string Id);
    ...
}
```

MyService.cs:

```
...
[ServiceBehavior( InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall )]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IMyDependency _myDependency;

    public MyService (IMyDependency myDependency)
    {
        _myDependency = myDependency;        
    } 

    public Object MyMethod( string Id )
    {
        // Method code here
    }
    ...
}
```

Global.asax:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Autofac initialization is actually in another class, but we call it here like this
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<MyService>().AsSelf();

        builder.RegisterType<MyDependency>().As<IMyDependency>();            

        var container = builder.Build();

        AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;
        ...
   }
}
```

Raw request from Fiddler:

```
GET http://localhost/MySolution/MyService.svc/MyMethod/12345 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/xml
Authorization: meyer.john
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [AutofacWebServiceHostFactory](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Wcf/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Integration.Wcf/AutofacWebServiceHostFactory.cs) instead of AutofacServiceHostFactory.

Comment: Thank You! This worked! There is no mention of this factory in the documentation at http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/ as of 9/12/2016.